# If statement based on the concat in Power Bi

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, concatenation, dax, daxstudio

I have 4 columns are A,B,C and D. Those 4 columns are contain number and text or number or text.

If column A&B and C&D are matched then return "Ok" and if column A&B and C&D are not matched then  return "No" and if column A&B or C&D are blanks then return "Blanks".

I am achieved my desired result by using duplicate column (A&B , C&D) but I want the same result without duplication columns.

A&B = 'DATA2'[A]&"-"&'DATA2'[B]

C&D = 'DATA2'[C]&"-"&'DATA2'[D]

RESULT = IF(DATA2[A&B]="-","NO",IF(DATA2[C&D]="-","NO", IF(DATA2[A&B] = DATA2[C&D],"OK","NO")))

I am attempted one more DAX for formula but that one also giving error **"Cannot convert value 'AA1' of type Text to type Number"**.

RESULT 1 = CALCULATE(
IF (
SUMX(
'DATA2',
'DATA2'[A]+'DATA2'[B]+'DATA2'[C]+'DATA2'[D])>0,0,1
))

I am looking for New calculated column option.

Any help much appreciated.

Data:

```html
A   B   C   D   DESIRED RESULT
AA1 TT1 DD1 XX1 NO
AA1 TT1 DD1 XX1 NO
AA1 TT1 DD1 XX1 NO
AA1 TT1 DD1 XX1 NO
AA1 TT1 DD1 XX1 NO
AA1 TT1 DD1 XX1 NO
AA1 TT2 DD1 XX2 NO
AA1 TT2 DD1 XX2 NO
AA1 TT2 DD1 XX2 NO
AA1 TT2 DD1 XX2 NO
AA1 TT2 DD1 XX2 NO
BB1 RR1 DD1 XX3 NO
BB1 RR1 DD1 XX3 NO
BB1 RR1 DD1 XX3 NO
BB1 RR1 DD1 XX3 NO
BB1 RR2 GG1 HH1 NO
BB1 RR2 GG1 HH2 NO
BB1 RR2 GG1 HH3 NO
                NO
                NO
                NO
                NO
BB1 RR2 BB1 RR2 OK
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve it:

```
Result = 
var AB = [A]&[B]
var CD = [C]&[D]

return  
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),

    // Blank return if both AB and CD are blank/null
    (ISBLANK(AB) || AB = "") && (ISBLANK(CD) || CD = ""), BLANK(), 

    // A1 return if AB or CD (but not both) are blank
    (ISBLANK(AB) || AB = "") || (ISBLANK(CD) || CD = ""), "A1",

    // OK return if AB = CD
    AB = CD, "OK",

    // Catch all remaining cases with NO
    "NO"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and. its working well. I need one more help. If AB is blank and CD is not blanks in this case I need a result "A1". If CD is blank and AB  is not blanks then I need a result "A1" as well.

Comment: I've updated the code to add the A1 option.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your response and modify the DAX code according to my request.

Comment: No worries, just let me know where to send the bill ;)

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late reply. I wish to pay more if you have a time to teach power bi.